# How scan two strings separated by `/` using sscanf?

Tags: c++, scanf, format-specifiers

I want to scan to separate strings separated by a `/` using `sscanf` but it doesn't work. It works fine with a space.

For example, I want to separate the string 50%/60% into two strings like 50% and 60%.

You can have a look at code [here](http://ideone.com/1x0un0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int extract_break_rewrites(int *m, int *n, const char *arg)
{
    char m_str[10];
    char n_str[10];
    int err;

    int count = sscanf(arg, "%s %s", n_str, m_str);
    printf("%s %s %d\n",n_str, m_str,count);
    if (count == 0) {
        count = sscanf(arg, "/%s", m_str);
        if (count == 0) {
            *m = 0;
            *n = 0;
            return -1;
        }
        if (sscanf(m_str, "%d%%", m) != 1) 
            return -1;
    }
    else if (count == 1) {
        if (sscanf(n_str, "%d%%", n) != 1) 
            return -1;
    }
    else if (count==2) {
        if (sscanf(n_str, "%d%%", n) != 1) 
            return -1;
        if (sscanf(m_str, "%d%%", m) != 1) 
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int n,m;
    const char * command = "50% 60%";
    if (extract_break_rewrites(&m,&n,command)!=-1)
        cout<<"Successful. The values of m and n are "<<m<<" and "<<n<<", respectively.\n";
    else
        cout<<"There was error in processing, may be input was not in the correct format.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to worry about what the code does, the important lines are 10, 11 and main function.

Comment: Please post the code here instead of a link to the code.

Comment: This is called an x-y problem.  You want to parse a string and you think `sscanf` is the proper tool.  It isn't.

Comment: Your code is written in C++, you should change your tag to C++. However if you want to parse strings you could use something like strtok to divide the string into tokens.

Comment: Code is written in C++, but the function library used is derived in C++ from C only, so don't think there is need to change it to C++. @DMH

Comment: @stark what is the correct tool then, please suggest.

Comment: @SaurabhJain C++ has better tools to use with strings which are safer and better than the ones from C. Any particular reason to be using C in C++ code?

Comment: You sample data doesn't include the `/` which your question discusses.  That's at least mildly confusing.  What should happen if the `%` symbols are missing?  What should happen if the `/` is missing?

Comment: This is C++, not C. Don't add C tag for C++ code.

Comment: Why -1 for the question, any reasons ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following (assuming from stdin):

```
scanf("%[^/]/%s");
```

Use `sscanf(buf, ...);` if reading from a buffer.

The issue is that `%s` for `scanf` assumes that the string is followed by a space. This approach instructs `scanf` to find a string delimited by `/`, and then match the rest as a separate string.

EDIT: accidentally dropped the `/` in the scan string

Comment: How does this scans two strings ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: The full code should be `if (sscanf(arg, "%9[^/]/%9s", n_str, m_str) == 2) { …OK… } else { …Deal with errors… }`.  The `9` is the amount of space in the string variables excluding the trailing null.

Answer (score 2):

Use a scan set

```
char a[100];
char b[100];
scanf("%[^/]/%s", a, b);
```

This scans in everything until it gets a `/`, then it starts and reads in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::string`s and their facilities to achieve the same result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::stoi;

bool extract_break_rewrites(int &m, int &n, const string &arg) {
    // find position of %/ in the string
    string::size_type pos_first = arg.find("%/");
    // check if the return value is valid (the substring is present and there
    // is something else first)
    if ( pos_first == string::npos  ||  !pos_first )    // wrong input
        return false;

    string::size_type pos_2 = pos_first + 2,
                      pos_last = arg.find("%", pos_2);
    if ( pos_last == string::npos  ||  pos_last == pos_2 )  
        return false;

    try {
        m = stoi(arg.substr(0, pos_first));
        n = stoi(arg.substr(pos_2, pos_last - pos_2));
    }
    // invalid argument or out of range
    catch (...) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    string command = "150%/60%";

    if ( extract_break_rewrites(m, n, command) )
        cout << "Successful. The values of m and n are "
             << m << " and " << n << ", respectively.\n";
    else
        cout << "There was error in processing, "
             << "maybe input was not in the correct format.\n";

    return 0;
}
```